# Is there a built in function in sql2000 that returns 0 or 0.00 if money or a float column is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Is there a simple built in function in sql2000 that returns 0 or 0.00 if money or a float column is null?  Or do I need to build the function myself, and how would I build it?  if (isnull(col1)) then 0 else col1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the function is called `ISNULL`, you use it like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(columnname, 0.0) AS xyz FROM tablename
```

You basically specify which value to return in case the first value is `null`.

Note that `ISNULL` does not return a boolean value indicating whether the parameter is `null` or not, instead you pass it 2 parameters and it does the following:

1. If the first argument is non-`null`, return the value of the first argument
2. Otherwise, return the second argument

You can also use the `COALESCE` function for this, which takes an unspecified number of parameters, and returns the first non-`null` argument value back, in the order they're specified.

In other words:

```
ISNULL(columnname, 0.0)
```

and

```
COALESCE(columnname, 0.0)
```

behaves the same, but I don't know if there is a difference in "sargeability" of these two, ie. whether they can use indexes or not.

Comment: I think you meant "sargable" as in "able to be used as a search argument". :-)

Comment: Any expression can't use an index, only direct colum references: `select coalesce(col1,0) from foo where coalesce(col1,0) = 0 ` can't use an index on `col1`, but `select coalesce(col1,0) from foo where col1 is null or col1 = 0` can, assuming that such an index exists and is deemed helpful by the optimizer. Ditto for ISNULL. Any expression pretty much kills index usage.